# Xamarin color bar with changeable width

Tags: colors, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I like to ask if there is anyway to make a bar of color in Xamarin.Forms with changeable Width? I've been searching around for a few days now but couldn't really find any topic about this. In my application, I have a range of number for people's weight: 100 lbs to 200 lbs is normal (yellow), below 100 lbs is underweight(green), above 200 lbs is overweight(red). Let's says the min and max weight is 0 lbs - 300 lbs which is being displayed as a white bar with **BoxView** and a person's weight is 160 lbs which is being passed to me from the database. I like to know how to display this person's weight in a green color bar with its width is that person's weight. Below is the image of what i'm trying to do. Any pointer in how to approach this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try layering 3 different BoxView on top of one another using an AbsoluteLayout, RelativeLayout, or Grid:

1. Black box for outer frame
2. White box for inner "unfilled" portion
3. Green box for "progress" portion

You could layer the green on top of the white, or try just placing them next to each other.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I was thinking of doing the way you said with **Grid**. But then how can I deal with the changing number of the "progress" portion? The **WidthRequest** attribute from **BoxView** doesn't let me bind the person's weight. I don't have control over this number as it is passed to me from a database.

Comment: You may not be able to bind WidthRequest, but you can set it based on a value from your db.

Comment: By that you means to hard code **WidthRequest="160"**?

Comment: No, in your xaml.cs set the value of the property.  MyGreenBox.WidthRequest = whatever_value_I_get_from_db;

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make it changeble by and making it a bindable property and redraw item on its change. As far as I can see, in Xamarin Forms BoxView the WidthRequest is already a bindable property, but I don't see it redraws element in renderer after this property changes. So you should create an inherited class and in its renderer do something like this

```
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(
        object sender, 
        PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == VisualElement.WidthRequestProperty.PropertyName
|| e.PropertyName == VisualElement.WidthProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            this.SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }
```